# Using 'require' in node.js to include functions from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use nodeJS, and I put this in the head of the file main.js:

```
var par = require("C:/Us/ht");
```

In the ht.js file, I have a function called `doJob()`.

When I then try the following code in main.js:

```
function cr(LTDa){
     par.doJob();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'doJob'
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Show us that `ht` file. "Having a function" is not enough.

Comment: You didn't give enough context. But whatever your problem is, odds are that you can solve it yourself by reading the relevant documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Actually there _is_ enough context to easily diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the function as an attribute of the exports object, as documented [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)

In other words, your ht.js file should have the following code inside it:

```
exports.doJob = function() {
     //your code here
};
```